# How to include a new file js in a project?

Tags: javascript, cocos2d-js

I'm trying to include a new js file containing a new scene on a cocos2d js project, but every time try occurs the following error: **Uncaught ReferenceError: GameScene is not defined.**

I included my file in jsList and in appList:
`"jsList"        : ["src/game_scene.js"],
    "appFiles"      : ["src/game_scene.js"]`

The code of my scene looks normal:

```js
var GameScene = cc.Scene.extend({
    onEnter:function(){
        this._super();
        
  var gameLayer = new GameLayer();
  this.addChild(gameLayer);
        
    }
});
```

The code on app.js to call my scene looks good too:

```js
var gameScene = new GameScene();
cc.Director.runScene(gameScene);
```

What i have to do?
Thanks!! :-)

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem. I included the file in "jsList" of "project.json".